# Exclude controllers, routes etc when loading rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want o use rails 3 app as some background worker with its models (for example). Could I run rails in some way that it doesn't load, say, controllers, routes and other unneeded stuff?

Comment: Can you give any more context / details?

Comment: You probably don't need Rails at all. `ActiveRecord` and, say, `Delayed::Job` should be enough.

Comment: Well, I want to use app for web and as daemon simultaneously